# Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle in netbeans

Tags: java

Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Result: 1
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: 
D:\softphone\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\softphone\build
clean:
deps-jar:

Created dir: D:\softphone\build

Updating property file: D:\softphone\build\built-jar.properties

Created dir: D:\softphone\build\classes

Created dir: D:\softphone\build\empty

Created dir: D:\softphone\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output

Compiling 192 source files to D:\softphone\build\classes

Note: D:\softphone\src\com...\softphone\LoginFrame.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Copying 17 files to D:\softphone\build\classes

compile:

Created dir: D:\softphone\dist

Copying 3 files to D:\softphone\dist\lib

Launching  task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre..\lib\ant-javafx.jar

Launching  task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre..\lib\ant-javafx.jar

Note: To create native bundles the  task may require external tools. See JavaFX 2.2+ documentation for details.

Launching  in native packager mode...

No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.

No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.

Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler8677317485582047638\images\win-exe.image\SoftPhone \app\SoftPhone .cfg (The system cannot find the path specified)

### D:\softphone\nbproject\build-native.xml:736: Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

how can fix this problem? can any body help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your

```
Project Title is "SoftPhone "
```

Change it to

```
"SoftPhone" in Project Properties > Application > Title
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is most likely this:

```
Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  C:\Users\Arobil\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler8677317485582047638\
  images\win-exe.image\SoftPhone \app\SoftPhone .cfg 
  (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I can see a couple of spaces in the pathname that probably shouldn't be there.  Check your project's build configs.